# How can I intercept segfaults in C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I am not a Windows developer(!) in any way, but I currently work on a Windows only project.

The project is *very* old and *a lot* of people have been working on it. It looks like the original development team took the big old book of anti-patterns and applied all of them wherever they saw it possible. Fixing bugs is hard. Much much harder than it should be. There are plenty of crashes and just general slowing down of stuff. When stuff crash, some resources still has to be cleaned up. In particular, the program *may* reserve some screen space for a tool bar -- not cleaning up that space means a part of the screen won't be available to other programmes.

I've tried several approaches, based on various other peoples attempts:

- using c-style signals (`<csignal>` -- setting signal handlers on all defined signals)
- using `std::set_terminate`
- using DllMain to set signals/terminate
- using __try/__except
- using `system` to invoke a copy of the program and communicating resources (a `HWND`) through the registry. This one was a long shot, but I had to try it.

None of them worked as hoped -- except the `system` bit, I couldn't get any of the error handling code to run at all.

We're using Visual Studio 2012, so we have C++(ish)11(ish) available.

Comment: You cannot really intercept segfaults or other types of SEH exceptions with the standard c++ methods. IIRC that's only possible via the debugging API, not sure if it's possible to go back to a recoverable state from there.

Comment: @user0042 I know I can't use standard C++ for stuff like this. Any other API that's available and part of what I have using VS2012, is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Hmm, there are also tools you could use for analysis like Smartbear AQTime.

Comment: I don't know if that's acceptable. Third party stuff isn't exactly welcome. Besides, we're not using .Net.

Comment: @user0042: SEH can use `__try` / `__except`. No need for debugging API's. The real problem is, you can not recover from a random bug in your program. A stack guard page exception is something you recover from without even noticing, as long as there's space for the stack to grow.

Comment: @MSalters I just need to know that something is broken so I can recover the space from the screen. Everything else is just icing on the cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments note, drop C++. You can't trust the C++ library anymore once your program has corrupted memory all over the place.

The first step is to figure out the event you're reacting to. "SegFault" is POSIX. Windows has Access Violations (the famous C0000005). This might also be why you were misled by `signal`. It's a bit of POSIX that ended up in C. Windows simply does not use `signal`.

The next step is how you react to them. My preference is a [Vectored Exception Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681420(v=vs.85).aspx). Structured Exception Handling assumes the stack is somewhat sane, and that too is a guess. A vectored Exception Handler in effect is a hard jump. We're not going to return, just doing cleanup before calling `TerminateProcess`. Same pattern again: `ExitProcess` is what you would use if the state of your program could be trusted, but we don't.

In your Vectored Exception Handler, you'll query the OS about the existence of that toolbar. Don't believe your own program: you can't trust it, and besides, if the OS doesn't think there's a toolbar, then there isn't one. Use the handle returned by the OS, and destroy that toolbar. Then commit suicide by `TerminateProcess`

Comment: I'll give it a go :-)

Comment: Just to reinforce - with structured and vectored exception handling - the word 'exception' here must NOT be confused with the words use in c++. It's an entirely different kind of exception.

Comment: @ChrisBecke I tried to explain my colleagues that in this context, exceptions in C++ aren't really relevant. I didn't succeed. If only we had a better word :-(

Comment: The CRT does implement a stack-based structured exception handler for `SIGSEGV` (`STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`), `SIGILL` (`STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION`, `STATUS_PRIVILEGED_INSTRUCTION`), and `SIGFPE` (`STATUS_FLOAT_*`). You can easily set up `signal(SIGSEGV, sigsegv_handler)` that will do cleanup and terminate the process.